# Recursive SQLite CTE with JSON1 json_each

Tags: sqlite, recursion, common-table-expression

I have a SQLite table where one column contains a JSON array containing 0 or more values. Something like this:

```
id|values
0 |[1,2,3]
1 |[]
2 |[2,3,4]
3 |[2]
```

What I want to do is "unfold" this into a list of all distinct values contained within the arrays of that column.

To start, I am using the JSON1 extension's json_each function to extract a table of values from a row:

```
SELECT
  value
FROM
  json_each(
      (
        SELECT
          values
        FROM
          my_table
        WHERE
          id == 2
      )
  )
```

Where I can vary the id (2, above) to select any row in the table.

Now, I am trying to wrap this in a recursive CTE so that I can apply it to each row across the entire table and union the results. As a first step I replicated (roughly) the results from above as follows:

```
WITH RECURSIVE result AS (
  SELECT null
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    value
  FROM
      json_each(
          (
            SELECT
              values
            FROM
              my_table
            WHERE
              id == 2
          )
      )  
)
SELECT * FROM result;
```

As the next step I had originally planned to make id a variable and increment it (in a similar manner to the first example in the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html#recursivecte), but haven't been able to get that to work.

I have gone through the other examples in the documentation, but they are somewhat more complex and I haven't been able to distill those down to see how they might apply to this problem.

Can someone provide a simple example of how to solve this (or a similar problem) with a recursive CTE?

Of course, my goal is to solve the problem with or without CTEs so Im also happy to hear if there is a better way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a recursive CTE for this.

To call `json_each` for multiple source rows, use a join:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.value
FROM my_table AS t1
JOIN json_each((SELECT "values" FROM my_table WHERE id = t1.id)) AS t2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
In my case the input was a [pmd](/questions/tagged/pmd) report in json format (using format `-f json`) which is nested multiple times like this

```json
{
  "formatVersion": 0, 
  "pmdVersion": "7.0.0-rc3", 
  "timestamp": "2023-08-19T01:11:39.497+02:00",
  "files": [
     { "filename": "D:\\A.cls", "violations": [ {v1}, {v2}, {v3} ]},
     { "filename": "D:\\B.cls", "violations": [ {v4}, {v5}, {v6} ]}
  ],
  "suppressedViolations": [],
  "processingErrors": [],
  "configurationErrors": []
}
```

Each file `[f1, f2]` inside the array `files: []` can have n violations `[v1, v2, v3]`

The SQL i used to extract the json objects and some properties looks like this

#### Using a Common Table Expression

```
WITH CTE1 AS(
 SELECT PMD_Reports.id, PMD_Reports.report_date, jsonEachFiles.value as File
     FROM PMD_Reports
          ,json_each(PMD_Reports.format_json, '$.files') AS jsonEachFiles
)
SELECT 
    CTE1.id, 
    CTE1.report_date, 
    substr(json_extract(CTE1.File, '$.filename'), 28) as filename,
    json_extract(jsonEachViolation.value, '$.ruleset') as ruleset,
    json_extract(jsonEachViolation.value, '$.rule') as rule,  
    json_extract(jsonEachViolation.value, '$.priority') as priority,
    json_extract(jsonEachViolation.value, '$.description') as description       
    FROM CTE1
         ,json_each(CTE1.File, '$.violations') AS jsonEachViolation
```

#### Using a subquery

```
SELECT ruleset, rule, priority, Count(Distinct filename) as files_affected FROM
(
  SELECT 
     T1.id,
     substr(json_extract(T1.Files, '$.filename'), 28) as filename, 
     json_extract(T2.value, '$.ruleset') as ruleset,
     json_extract(T2.value, '$.rule') as rule,  
     json_extract(T2.value, '$.priority') as priority,
     json_extract(T2.value, '$.description') as description
    FROM (
          SELECT PMD_Reports.id, jsonEachFiles.Value as Files
          FROM PMD_Reports
          ,json_each(PMD_Reports.format_json, '$.files') AS jsonEachFiles           
    ) AS T1, json_each(T1.Files, '$.violations') as T2
) as T3
GROUP BY T3.ruleset, T3.rule, T3.priority
```

Broken down

- `json_each(PMD_Reports.format_json, '$.files')` unwraps the `files-array` and results in one row per file.
- `json_each(T1.Files, '$.violations')` unwraps each violation for every file
- `json_extract(T2.value, '$.priority') as priority,` reads the property `priority` of a violation (`T2.value` contains the violation object)